# Reparenting Bone, but there's a glitch

Tags: animation

How do I fix this message?
[image]

I need to reparent a bone to fix a glitch, but this little guy pops up.

Comment: Can you please describe more precisely, what you did to bring this message up?

Comment: Seems like you aren't allowed to use that function, I know for sure that parenting works with some functions, could you attach the .blend and discribe which armature you want to reparent to what mesh?

Comment: Actually, I'm posting an answer on how I figured this out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I'm stupid. You can only re-parent bones from the Edit menu.